# Xamarin Forms: Values vanished/refreshed on swiping more than four content pages inside carousel page or tabbed page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel, mobile-development, tabbedpage

I am working on a xamarin forms project which have a carousel page container, and content pages as its children are created dynamically on different condition checks. (Minimum 8 children in my case)

Let's take the mentioned minimum case. I enter some values in entry/picker controls in the 1st child and then navigate/swipe pages till 5th child. When I came back to the first child page, the values I entered/selected are now vanished/refreshed.

I have noticed that carousel page saves only **3 pages data** in it. i.e. (Left Page, **Current Page** and the Right Page). 
And Tabbed page saves **4 pages data**.

I want the values to stay in the child page where I entered whether I navigate to the last most page or in the middle and navigate back to that page.

I have googled via the letters as "**Carousel page/ Tabbed page Saved states**" etc. but unable to find something useful.

So, I need to know the **property name/ method name** etc. by which xamarin forms setting the limit of carousel page as 3 and tabbed page as 4.

Waiting for your response.

Thanks.

Comment: Save the content page state via the page lifecycles and restore them when needed, otherwise you will need to modify the Xamarin.Forms source code. MultiPage is where you would need to start as it is the abstract class that is used as the Page "container" for TabbedPage and CarouselPage : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/bd31e1e9fc8b2f9ad94cc99e0c7ab058174821f3/Xamarin.Forms.Core/MultiPage.cs

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks. but the issue is that I have not created any custom control yet even modification. so I don't know what, where and how to modify in the page life-cycles to save and retrieve states. Can you please provide the documentation link for page life-cycles? it will be really appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentpage?view=xamarin-forms#events

Comment: @SushiHangover if it's an event of a ContentPage, then how it's possible that CarouselPage saves different number of ContentPage states than TabbedPage? with same number of ContentPages in both?

Comment: CarouselPage/TabbedPage are not saving any "state", it is a form of recycling. It creates and releases pages based upon usage. You could have a hundred catalog items bound to the carousel and as the user swipes between them, they are getting create/referenced and then de-referenced and garbage collected as you would very quickly runout of memory if all hundred pages were statically/hard referenced by the carousel. (Same idea when using a ListView in recycler mode), in fact the original CarouselPage code did just that and was un-usable in any real-world usage

Comment: @SushiHangover umm so what should I do now for my specific requirement? My requirement is to save the states of all content pages in carouselpage whether it's 10 pages or 100. Should I modify the default saving state number? or I should make my own methodology to satisfy the requirement? What would you recommend?

Comment: In very general terms you would need to persist the state of the data for each page (i.e. Sqlite, Realm, json file, etc...) and when the page is created (or shown), you are binding it to a data model (assumably a ViewModel if you are using MVVM) and the page UI elements are bound to that model and thus visually represent the model, at least until you clear that persistent data (or the user does if permitted via the UI) as the page's UI is altered by the user, it is updating the ViewModel via bindings and the underlaying persistent store is updated to match.

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes I am using MVVM. And already binded View to ViewModel and the data shown on the page is fetched from Webserver on page creation. Data is fetched upon 4 picker's selected values. Issue is that I am creating pages dynamically. So unable to specify the pages to remember values which user selected or set upon creation time. Carousel page swipe sets the created values to default first values of each picker. by this value refreshing, the data fetching querry is totally changing. And server is also getting too much hits.

Comment: Create a session based cache for the page data required to preserve the state locally and if that data exists for a particular page re-used it, otherwise you would call your server API to obtain the data as you are currently doing. There are a large number of caching frameworks (like Akavache) that can be used to help.

Comment: @SushiHangover Ok now I figured out that the Value refreshing issue is with the Custom Renderer Picker which I am using for Android. But still unable to resolve this issue. How I can share Custom Renderer Implementation code with you? via comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found that I was using a Custom Picker Control and the value refreshing issue is with it. I just forget to set the **selectedIndex** of the picker on **OnElementChanged** event.